# AngularJS $stateParams.id is always undefined

Tags: angularjs

I can't for many hours figured it out what is wrong with my code. $stateParams.id is always undefined. 
This is **my controller**:

```
.controller('ordersCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$http',
    '$stateParams',
    'orders',
    'meals',
    function($scope, $http, $stateParams, orders, meals){
        console.log($stateParams.id); 
    ...
 }])
```

**My state**:

```
.state('orders/{id}', {
    url: '/orders',
    templateUrl: '/orders.html',
    controller: 'ordersCtrl'
})
```

And **my link**:

```
<a href="#/orders/{{$index}}">Order</a>
```

What is wrong with that?

Comment: Using index for identifier is not very practical. Remove or add just one item anywhere in array other than the end and bookmarking is destroyed

Comment: so what can I do when I have only one state?

Comment: use unique ID's that never change

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your state should read:

```
.state('orders_view', {
    url: '/orders/:id',
    templateUrl: '/orders.html',
    controller: 'ordersCtrl'
})
```

First parameter of `state()` is just a label. It does not care about parameters. That is reserved for the `url`.

Also, the correct form of the link is:

```
<a href ui-sref="orders_view({id: $index})">Order</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the syntax could be different for the parameter. you could try change the code like this:

```
.state('orders/:id', {
    url: '/orders',
    templateUrl: '/orders.html',
    controller: 'ordersCtrl'
})
```

i hope this help you

Comment: This doesn't work because you're trying to set the $stateParam on the state name.